# Аргументы в командах discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Делаю небольшого бота-переводчика для дискорда. Проблема в том, что он принимает на вход только первое слово, остальное просто пропускает. Каким образом можно сделать, чтобы он принимал все предложение в один аргумент, а не только первое слово?

```
    async def text(self, ctx, arg):
        if arg == '':
            await ctx.send('Использование: "!!text <текст>"')
        else:
            translate = translate_req + '&' + 'text=' + arg + '&' + 'lang=' + self.lang
            response = requests.get(translate)
            if response:
                json_response = response.json()
                await ctx.send(json_response['text'][0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно еще написать так:

```
async def text(self, ctx, *, arg):
```

получает полное сообщение

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение сам. Чтобы получить несколько слов через пробел как один аргумент, можно использовать *" "* в начале и в конце аргумента. Так же есть *"args"*, который является списком и его можно превратить в строку методом *join*